# Additional example determining Marcus parameters searched

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, electronic-configuration

Background / theory: The electron transfer in organic materials was formalized by the Marcus theory, introducing $|H_{ab}|$ to describe the how molecules (or more generally: sites) are coupled with each other, and reorganization energy $\lambda$, about how costly it is to to accommodate a charge *after* the carrier moved.  Especially if the atomic coordinates of the material already are known, it is possible to access these parameters by quantum chemical calculations.

Background / software: [NWChem](http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Main_Page) *seems* to be one of the freely available programs allowing such an additional characterization.  New to this program, I found both the standard entry in the manual ([here](http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Electron_Transfer)), as well as a post in the user forum ([here](http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Special:AWCforum/st/id562/Electron_transfer_between_two_di....html)) by 2012, comparing the result to a literature reference in [Phys Rev B 2007](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.77.115210) as "work[ing] pretty well".  It is possible for me to to replicate the computation filed there under "Sep 19th 2012", too.

The feeling: It seems dangerously simple to use this script for an other structure, just replacing the first / second / third block of coordinates by the $(x,y,z)$ extracted from X-ray diffraction analyses about molecule A, hoovering neighbor B, and the close couple / dimer (AB).  Indeed, my first tests (again, as a beginner) failed; the program launched, yet eventually shut down -- likely because I do not know well enough how to proceed.

The question: Does one of you know about an additional tutorial, starting from accessible atom coordinates of molecular materials, concluding with the Marcus parameters of the electron hopping?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. It sounds like you want to run a particular NWChem calculation, but change the coordinates. If so, it would help to know the specific errors you're getting, rather than just 'eventually shut down.'

Comment: There's also an NWChem forum, which may be helpful: http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Special:AWCforum

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Yes I would like to use NWChem to determine Marcus parameters, eventually with coordinates about other materials.  Like as the post by "St" (Oct 25th 2015) I was wondering about the large coupling (0.92 eV) even if the antracenes in the preceedingly post form a sandwich, only 3 \AA apart from each other.  Other typical organic electronics e.g., the better polymorph of rubrenes are reported just around 0.1..0.2 eV (with far less superposition, of course).  So it still is a search for «more realistic» coordinates, with partial overlap of the $\pi$-systems only and determined MPs.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison  As I recall, many, yet not all «shut downs» were caused by input errors of mine -- which anyway I'll check again tomorrow, and I already deposit a question in their forum *prior* to ChemSE, too.